# How to use callback in flutter for background location

Tags: flutter, background, location

I am following this plugin (learning) [background locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator/example)  . I have previously used other background location plugins but they are not maintained anymore.

I am following the tutorial as described in the description of the plugin and so far this is my code.
I am unsure about what exactly a callback is and how do I use it.

This is my code so far but I don't get any results.

```
static void backgroundLocationCallBack(LocationDto location) async {
    await BackgroundLocator.initialize();
    await BackgroundLocator.isServiceRunning();
  }

  void getLocationLiveUpdates() async {
    return await BackgroundLocator.registerLocationUpdate(
        backgroundLocationCallBack,
        autoStop: false,
        // disposeCallback: backgroundLocationDisposeCallBack,

        androidSettings: AndroidSettings(
            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION,
            interval: 5,
            distanceFilter: 0,
            client: LocationClient.google,
            androidNotificationSettings: AndroidNotificationSettings(
              notificationChannelName: 'Location tracking',
              notificationTitle: 'Start Location Tracking',
              notificationMsg: 'Track location in background',
              notificationBigMsg:
                  'Background location is on to keep the app up-tp-date with your location. This is required for main features to work properly when the app is not running.',
              notificationIconColor: Colors.grey,
            )));
  }
```

Comment: Facing few issues in working with background_locator. Can anyone provide me with a working example for tracking background location if the issue's resolved.
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72246232/issue-while-using-background-locator-plugin-while-tracking-background-location-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks are used to perform some actions during certain events.

Here, the `callback` attribute takes `backgroundLocationCallBack` as its value, and as per the package code, it is used for performing appropriate actions when the `LocationDto` is available. This `LocationDto` object will contain the Location information you are looking for, and you can use it according to your use-case.

Similarly, `disposeCallback` is used to perform certain actions when dispose is called on the `BackgroundLocator` object. You can do something like close all the Ports that were opened for fetching the location.

There are other callbacks as well such as `initCallback` and `initDataCallback` which are used for setting the callbacks to initialise various parameters for your location service and to provide an initial data for the params respectively.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now, Could you please help me with the code, I am trying to print the location (latitude & longitude). I have been at it for weeks but so far unable to do so.

Comment: try to print the `location` object like this :

`location.toString()` in the callback method.

If you read through the class code for `LocationDto` , you can find all the data members that are available for the object.

https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/blob/master/lib/location_dto.dart

Comment: I've been facing similar issues in working with background_locator. Can anyone provide me with a working example for tracking background location if the issue's resolved.
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72246232/issue-while-using-background-locator-plugin-while-tracking-background-location-i