# Issue while using background_locator plugin while tracking background location in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, background

I'm trying to track location in the background using flutter and to do so I'm using the [background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) plugin. It has been implemented in such a way that there are certain static callback functions that were registered. I've declared a class variable of File type to save the log in the background. The global variable is built at the very beginning of the class.

Issue: While invoking the callback method, the global variable built is becoming null. So though I could see the location log in my console, I couldn't write it to the file as the object is null.

Tries:

1. I've tried with the exact example provided in their documentation.
2. I've declared it as non static property and tried to access with the class object.
3. Tried it out declaring it as static property as well.
4. Tried building file object with the same path every time needed but it is throwing following issue.

> No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Here is my complete source code for reference.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:background_locator/background_locator.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/location_dto.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/settings/android_settings.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/settings/ios_settings.dart';
import 'package:background_locator/settings/locator_settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart' as ph;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();

  String logStr = '';
  bool isRunning = false;
  LocationDto? lastLocation;

  bool permissionsGranted = false;

  static const String isolateName = 'LocatorIsolate';

  static int _count = -1;

  static File? finalFile;

  void requestPermission() async {
    var storageStatus = await ph.Permission.storage.status;

    if (!storageStatus.isGranted) {
      await ph.Permission.storage.request();
    }

    if (storageStatus.isGranted) {
      permissionsGranted = true;
      setPrerequisites();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  static Future<void> init(Map<dynamic, dynamic> params) async {
    //TODO change logs
    print("***********Init callback handler");
    if (params.containsKey('countInit')) {
      dynamic tmpCount = params['countInit'];
      if (tmpCount is double) {
        _count = tmpCount.toInt();
      } else if (tmpCount is String) {
        _count = int.parse(tmpCount);
      } else if (tmpCount is int) {
        _count = tmpCount;
      } else {
        _count = -2;
      }
    } else {
      _count = 0;
    }
    print("$_count");
    await setLogLabel("start");
    final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    send?.send(null);
  }

  static Future<void> disposeLocationService() async {
    await setLogLabel("end");
    final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    send?.send(null);
  }

  static Future<void> callback(LocationDto locationDto) async {
    await setLogPosition(_count, locationDto);
    final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    send?.send(locationDto);
    _count++;
  }

  static Future<void> setLogLabel(String label) async {
    final date = DateTime.now();
    await _MyAppState().writeToLogFile(
        '------------\n$label: ${formatDateLog(date)}\n------------\n');
  }

  static Future<void> setLogPosition(int count, LocationDto data) async {
    final date = DateTime.now();
    await _MyAppState().writeToLogFile(
        '$count : ${formatDateLog(date)} --> ${formatLog(data)} --- isMocked: ${data.isMocked}\n');
  }

  static double dp(double val, int places) {
    num mod = pow(10.0, places);
    return ((val * mod).round().toDouble() / mod);
  }

  static String formatDateLog(DateTime date) {
    return date.hour.toString() +
        ":" +
        date.minute.toString() +
        ":" +
        date.second.toString();
  }

  static String formatLog(LocationDto locationDto) {
    return dp(locationDto.latitude, 4).toString() +
        " " +
        dp(locationDto.longitude, 4).toString();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (permissionsGranted) {
      setPrerequisites();
    } else {
      requestPermission();
    }
  }

  void setPrerequisites() async {
    finalFile = await _getTempLogFile();

    if (IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName) != null) {
      IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping(isolateName);
    }

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(port.sendPort, isolateName);

    port.listen(
      (dynamic data) async {
        await updateUI(data);
      },
    );
    initPlatformState();

    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> updateUI(LocationDto data) async {
    final log = await readLogFile();

    await _updateNotificationText(data);

    setState(() {
      if (data != null) {
        lastLocation = data;
      }
      logStr = log;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _updateNotificationText(LocationDto data) async {
    if (data == null) {
      return;
    }

    await BackgroundLocator.updateNotificationText(
        title: "new location received",
        msg: "${DateTime.now()}",
        bigMsg: "${data.latitude}, ${data.longitude}");
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    print('Initializing...');
    await BackgroundLocator.initialize();
    logStr = await readLogFile();
    print('Initialization done');
    final _isRunning = await BackgroundLocator.isServiceRunning();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = _isRunning;
    });
    print('Running ${isRunning.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final start = SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Start'),
        onPressed: () {
          _onStart();
        },
      ),
    );
    final stop = SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Stop'),
        onPressed: () {
          onStop();
        },
      ),
    );
    final clear = SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Clear Log'),
        onPressed: () {
          clearLogFile();
          setState(() {
            logStr = '';
          });
        },
      ),
    );
    String msgStatus = "-";
    if (isRunning != null) {
      if (isRunning) {
        msgStatus = 'Is running';
      } else {
        msgStatus = 'Is not running';
      }
    }
    final status = Text("Status: $msgStatus");

    final log = Text(
      logStr,
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter background Locator'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[start, stop, clear, status, log],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onStop() async {
    await BackgroundLocator.unRegisterLocationUpdate();
    final _isRunning = await BackgroundLocator.isServiceRunning();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = _isRunning;
    });
  }

  void _onStart() async {
    if (await _checkLocationPermission()) {
      await _startLocator();
      final _isRunning = await BackgroundLocator.isServiceRunning();

      setState(() {
        isRunning = _isRunning;
        lastLocation = null;
      });
    } else {
      // show error
    }
  }

  static Future<void> initCallback(Map<dynamic, dynamic> params) async {
    await init(params);
  }

  static Future<void> disposeCallback() async {
    await disposeLocationService();
  }

  Future<void> locationServicecallback(LocationDto locationDto) async {
    await callback(locationDto);
  }

  static Future<void> notificationCallback() async {
    print('***notificationCallback');
  }

  Future<void> writeToLogFile(String log) async {
    await finalFile!.writeAsString(log, mode: FileMode.append);
  }

  Future<String> readLogFile() async {
    return finalFile!.readAsString();
  }

  static Future<File?> _getTempLogFile() async {
    File file =
        File('${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/log.txt');

    if (file.existsSync()) {
      return file;
    } else {
      file = await file.create(recursive: true);
    }
    return file;
  }

  Future<void> clearLogFile() async {
    await finalFile!.writeAsString('');
  }

  Future<bool> _checkLocationPermission() async {
    final access = await LocationPermissions().checkPermissionStatus();
    switch (access) {
      case PermissionStatus.unknown:
      case PermissionStatus.denied:
      case PermissionStatus.restricted:
        final permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions(
          permissionLevel: LocationPermissionLevel.locationAlways,
        );
        if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      case PermissionStatus.granted:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _startLocator() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {'countInit': 1};
    return await BackgroundLocator.registerLocationUpdate(
      callback,
      initCallback: initCallback,
      initDataCallback: data,
      disposeCallback: disposeCallback,
      iosSettings: const IOSSettings(
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION, distanceFilter: 0),
      autoStop: false,
      androidSettings: const AndroidSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION,
        interval: 5,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        client: LocationClient.google,
        androidNotificationSettings: AndroidNotificationSettings(
          notificationChannelName: 'Location tracking',
          notificationTitle: 'Start Location Tracking',
          notificationMsg: 'Track location in background',
          notificationBigMsg:
              'Background location is on to keep the app up-tp-date with your location. This is required for main features to work properly when the app is not running.',
          notificationIconColor: Colors.grey,
          notificationTapCallback: notificationCallback,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Struggling with same issue.
Not getting callback in callback function.
Any work around for background location is flutter?

Answer (score 1):

The callback function not getting called was an issue I faced inthe version 1.6.12.

I fixed the problem by

1. forking the background_locator repo on github.
2. cloning the repo to my computer
3. opened the location_dto.dart file and went to `fromJson` function.
4. added json[Keys.ARG_PROVIDER] ?? '' instead
5. commited and pushed to my forked repository
6. in pubspec.yaml, I updated my dependency to point to my forked repository as follows:

```
  background_locator:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:frankvollebregt/background_locator.git
```

Please follow these two github issues if you find any problem:

- https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/issues/320
- https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/issues/301

Comment: Thank you Oumar for your response. But I still couldn't execute the example checking out from your branch. The issue I've been facing is the logs are not written properly to the file. Every time it is trying to create the log file, it is throwing an issue. Can you share the working example if you have on your git?!

Answer (score 1):

background_locator dosen't work on latest flutter sdk versions
for me it's worked when I do this steps

- Flutter sdk version should be :3.0.1
- In pubspec.yaml file change sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"
- Don't migrate your code to null safety
- in gradle-wrapper.properties change gradle version to gradle-6.5
- android/build gradle change ext.kotlin_version to '1.4.31'
- android/app/build gradle change compileSdkVersion to 31, minSdkVersion to 19 and targetSdkVersion to 30

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the background locator plugin. When the plugin/library is not registered with Flutter Engine, the 'No implementation' error occurs.

You have been attempting to access the path provider methods from within a Background Isolate. Normally, the path provider plugin will be registered with main isolate.

If you want to use it in your background isolate, you must manually register it with the engine.

Follow the steps below and add these two functions to the Init function in `location_service_repositary.dart`

> if (Platform.isAndroid) PathProviderAndroid.registerWith();
> if (Platform.isIOS) PathProviderIOS.registerWith();

Have a good day.